# QT project with database after windeploqt not working fine

Tags: c++, mysql, database, qt, deployment

I've made my application which is connected to database hosting on db4free.net
everything works fine on my computer but when i'm trying login to app on other pc there is no connection with database this is my code to conecting to DB:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("db4free.net");
db.setUserName("MYLOGINTOPHPADMIN");
db.setPassword("MYPASSWORDTOPHPADMIN");
db.setPort(3306);
db.setDatabaseName("gamblingapp");
if(!db.open())
{
    qDebug() << "Failed!";
}
else{ qDebug() << "Connected!";}
```

in folder with exe i have libmysql.dll and sqldrivers

Comment: can you ping the host server ? did you check your firewall settings btw. is port 3306 allowed ?

Comment: On my PC works fine but on other PC's is not working
Pinging db4free.net [85.10.205.173] with 32 bytes of data:
Replay from 85.10.205.173: bytes = 32 time = 27 ms TTL = 51
Replay from 85.10.205.173: bytes = 32 time = 142 ms TTL = 51
Replay from 85.10.205.173: bytes = 32 time = 24ms TTL = 51
Replay from 85.10.205.173: bytes = 32 time = 26ms TTL = 51

Ping statistic for 85.10.205.173:
Packets: Sent = 4, Inbox = 4, Lost = 0
(0% loss),
Aproxinate round trip times in milliseconds:
Minimum = 24 ms, Maximum = 142 ms, Mean Time = 54 ms

Comment: @StPiere do You know how to fix it?